# StackExtend - A Google Chrome Extension to enhance the Stack Exchange experience

Tags: app, chrome-extensions

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[screenshot removed ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising/264155#264155))]

*Last Read Tracking - StackExtend tracks what questions you have previously viewed and indicates whether they have been read, and whether new answers are available on question summary pages.*

[screenshot removed ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising/264155#264155))]

*Extended User Information - StackExtend will include user information from all Stack Exchange sites when viewing a question*.

### About

StackExtend is a Google Chrome extension intended to augment the user experience on the Stack Exchange "trilogy" of sites (as well as Meta Stack Overflow, and soon, additional Stack Exchange sites). For now, it does a couple of things:

- **Last Read Tracking** - As you browse Stack Overflow, Super User, or Server Fault, the extension will keep track of what questions you have viewed and the answer count of these questions. Whenever you are viewing a summary page, a subtle highlight will indicate both read questions, and read questions with new answers since your last view.
- **User Information Extension** - Whenever you view a question page within the trilogy of sites, StackExtend will extend the user information box with the reputation, and badge count of the user on the rest of the trilogy of sites.

#### License

GPL v3.

#### Download

Source code is available for this extension at: http://bitbucket.org/enki42/stackextend

If you'd prefer to just install the extension, it is listed on the Google Chrome Extensions directory at: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cmbdgcnpckblnfmeagikpmblnblnkaln

#### Platform

StackExtend is a Google Chrome extension, and so is available for anyone running Google Chrome as their browser.

### Contact

For any questions or comments, please feel free to e-mail me at ryan@ryanbrunner.com.

You can browse our wiki or log any issues at http://bitbucket.org/enki42/stackextend (which is exceptionally sparse at the moment).

If you're interested in contributing to this extension, please feel free to let me know - my goal is to make this a treasure trove of various goodies to make Stack Overflow more effective for the "power user".

### Code

StackExtend is written entirely in JavaScript, making heavy use of jQuery to parse through the Stack Exchange pages.

The source code is freely available at http://bitbucket.org/enki42/stackextend.

Comment: Please consider listing StackExtend on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Comment: Ryan, can you spare a few moments for http://stackapps.com/questions/1115/need-some-help-verifying-503-throttle-issue ?

Comment: Can not view the images. Images expired, dead

Answer (score 2):

As seen in Stack Overflow question *[Why, in Ruby, does Array(“foo\nbar”) == [“foo\n”, “bar”]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027952/why-in-ruby-does-arrayfoo-nbar-foo-n-bar)*, I get undefined gold badges and undefined silver badges (and quite likely undefined bronze badges) on Super User for [Tyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43004?tab=accounts#tab-top), who has instead exactly 0 badges.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error a short while after I installed the extension:

> We're sorry...
>
> There are an unusual number of
>   requests coming from this IP address.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process
>   any more requests from this IP address
>   right now.
>
> We'll restore access as quickly as
>   possible, so try again soon.
>
> If you believe you have reached this
>   page in error, contact us.

Comment: I dug into this a bit, and it does look like making multiple API calls when visiting a StackOverflow site seems to be the culprit. This app will call the "home" sites API once, and the "child" sites APIs once per user on a question, so that's triggering something. Hopefully I can find a resolution to this - I'll keep everyone posted.

Comment: The extension has now been updated to queue incoming requests, and hopefully not trigger and DDNS detection on StackExchange sites. If you installed via the chrome extensions gallery, it should update itself soon, or you can expand the "Developer" section and click on "Update All Extensions". Let me know if you see any more problems. I just tried hammering meta for a while and it seems to be fine now.

Comment: see http://stackapps.com/questions/1043 @ryan